# Objective-C: How to generate one unique NSInteger from two NSIntegers?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass two integers as one integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738480/pass-two-integers-as-one-integer)

Will this work in Objective-C?
[Pass two integers as one integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738480/pass-two-integers-as-one-integer)

If so, how do I do it with `NSInteger`?

I'm asking because I want to calculate a unique `NSInteger tag` from the `NSUInteger`s `row` & `section` of a `UITableView`?

See, I'm dealing with a `UITableViewController` that has three sections, which each have multiple rows. Every row has a `UISwitch`, and each `UISwitch` is linked to the same target-action method, `switchAction:`.

In `switchAction:`, my plan is to inspect the `sender`'s `tag` to figure out the `UISwitch`'s `NSIndexPath` (`section` & `row`) of the `UITableView`.

So, I want two methods like:

```
+ (NSInteger)integerFromInteger1:(NSInteger)int1 integer2:(NSInteger)int2;
+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathFromInteger:(NSInteger)integer;
```

The first method may work better written in C. That works too if you prefer.

Comment: I have no idea why you want to use tag this way, but you've already linked to another SO question that answers this one.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard, OK, well what approach would you take so that you can figure out which switch sent the `switchAction:` message?

Comment: The switch sends itself as the first argument to `switchAction:`. You already know that, since you stated that your plan was to inspect the `sender`'s `tag` (where the `sender` is the switch).

Comment: @Kevin Ballard, right. Sorry, what I meant was [how do you figure out the index path of the `UISwitch`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514112/objective-c-how-to-generate-one-unique-nsinteger-from-two-nsintegers/6515240#6515240)? Thanks for your suggestion. I think I found a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [@benzado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514112/objective-c-how-to-generate-one-unique-nsinteger-from-two-nsintegers/6514483#6514483), I came up with a beautiful solution for how to get the index path of the `UISwitch` that sent the `switchAction:` message.

```
- (void)switchAction:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *onOff = (UISwitch *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:
                              (UITableViewCell *)[onOff superview]];
    // carry on...
}
```

No tags necessary. Just keep your pants on.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's safe to assume that the `superview` of a `UITableViewCell`'s `accessoryView` is the `UITableViewCell` itself. E.g., what if Apple decided to change this? I guess, as @benzado suggests, using a loop would be better. Or, just use a tag if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than messing around with bit-shifting, try this:

First, find the UITableViewCell containing the UISwitch. If you have a custom UITableViewCell subclass, just direct the UISwitch's target/action to a method on the cell that contains it. If you are using a stock UITableViewCell, you could find the UITableViewCell containing the UISwitch by calling `superview` in a loop.

Once you have the UITableViewCell, call a method on your view controller (or whatever has access to the UITableView) and you can call UITableView's `indexPathForCell:` method to get an NSIndexPath object with the section and row.

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to convert An NSInteger to an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752701/how-to-convert-nsinteger-to-int), `NSInteger` will always be at least 32 bits on every system/architecture, so yes, the answers to [Pass two integers as one integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738480/pass-two-integers-as-one-integer) will work.