# Converting int to NSInteger

Tags: iphone, ios, integer, nsinteger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert An NSInteger to an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752701/how-to-convert-an-nsinteger-to-an-int)

I am new to iOS programming, how do I convert int to NSInteger. I have found references on how to convert NSInteger to NSNumber but I wasn't able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752701/how-to-convert-an-nsinteger-to-an-int

Comment: Not a dupe, I believe, at least not of the proposed original. Converting apples into apple sauce is *not* the same as trying to convert apple sauce back into an apple :-)

Comment: This isn't how to turn apple sauce into apples, @paxdiablo, it's how to turn apples into _Malus domesticae_.

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate? Two different questions. Casting from int (32bit) to NSInt (64bit) is easy and automatic, this is asking how to cast from NSInt(64) to int(32). Re-open.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### An improved answer

On 64-bit systems `NSInteger` is `long`. On 32-bit systems `NSInteger` is `int`.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html

All you need just cast your `int` to `NSInteger`.

```
int i = 1;
NSInteger nsi = (NSInteger) i;
```

You can also cast `NSInteger` to `int` (as in an original answer), but you must be careful on 64-bit system, because your `NSInteger` can exceed `int` limits.

### An original answer

```
int i;
NSInteger nsi = 1;
i = nsi;
```

No big science. :)

Comment: In which way does this explain how to create an NSInteger from an int?

Comment: @kb You are right! My original answer showed only how to cast `NSInteger` to `int`. I have improved my answer to include a more precise answer to the question.

Comment: This just saved me hours of finding a bug after updating an iOS app to support 64Bit Architecture.

Comment: Suppress cast warning in 64 base system using `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"`