# NSUserDefaults always returns 1 instead of correct integer

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm attempting to store the current level for my game in NSUserDefaults but it always returns 1 when I try to convert it to an int.  Here's the test code:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:34 forKey:@"Current Level"];
    NSLog(@"default level raw: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Current Level"]);
    self.levelNum = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Current Level"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"default level num: %i", self.levelNum);
```

And the output:

```
default level raw: 34
default level num: 1
```

Comment: what is "`levelNum`" declared as?

Comment: levelNum is declared as an int.

Answer (score 5):

Just make sure to call synchronize on NSUSerDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setInteger:34 forKey:@"Current Level"];
NSLog(@"default level raw: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"Current Level"]);

[defaults synchronize]; // Call synchronize after set

self.levelNum = [defaults integerForKey:@"Current Level"];
NSLog(@"default level num: %i", self.levelNum);
```

Comment: its better to use [defaults integerForKey:@"Current Level"]);

Comment: Great tips, thanks!  I pasted your code in verbatim and it's still giving me 34 for the raw and 1 for the integer value.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Hmm.. I tried the code and of course I can't replicate what you are saying... anything else (another thread) potentially running setInteger:1?

Comment: @JamesMorrison, really? I pasted abellina's code in verbatim and I got 34 for both. How did you define levelNum in your .h file?

Comment: Don't think so.  Previous to adding the levelnumber I'm populating the defaults with an array of options from options.plist.  Not sure how that could effect it.  Doing a dump of the defaults shows current level to be 34.  It seems to be the conversion to integer that's causing it to become 1?

Comment: int _levelNum;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int levelNum;

Comment: I am not too sure here, but what about if you set _levelNum directly? I think it has to do with the property and the assign. You could try using the setLevelNum selector.

Comment: Well, I've done the same and I get 34 for both -- there's nothing wrong with the posted code (either your original or Abellina's), there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 3):

One thing about your code is that you're using "`setInteger`" (which is a NSInteger)

```
[defaults setInteger:34 forKey:@"Current Level"];
```

with

```
self.levelNum = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Current Level"] intValue]
```

which assumes you're returning a NSNumber object from which you are reading an "`int`" from (not necessarily the same thing as a "`NSInteger`").

Instead of that second call, use:

```
self.levelNum = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] integerForKey: @"Current Level"];
```

["`integerForKey:"`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/integerForKey%3a) is the correct method to use when you're using "`setInteger:forKey:`".

Comment: Ah, right you are.  Well that was one issue, although the problem still persists.

Comment: change your "`levelNum`" declaration from "`int`" to "`NSInteger`" and lemme know if that behaves a bit better for you.

Comment: NSInteger is a typedef equivalent to int or long: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1753275/1344738

Comment: Changed to NSInteger.  Still saying 1.  So weird.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. My. God.  I'm an idiot.  I forgot that I had a custom setLevelNum method defined to prevent the level from being set outside the bounds of the existing levels.  Since the code above occurs before I've defined the level set, it automatically sets it to the lowest level, which is 1.  Removed that and now it works.  Thanks everybody for your help.  At least I learned a lot about Objective-C data types :-)